# Python - find element if the previous contains specific type value in xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I was struggling to find a way to match an element if there is a previous element that contains a specific name.

Let's take as an example the following HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" name="name">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" name="email">
</div>
<div>
    <input class="bla">
</div>
<!-- there might be more divs between the email / name and the button that I want to press-->
<div>
    <button class="something" type="Submit"></button>
</div>
```

I want to click on the element of `type="submit"` (instead of `button` tag there can be anything) if it is after an element that contains `name="email"` or `name="name"`.

To match `name` and `email` and complete them with some values I have this:

```
# some variables and booleans defined here
# (...)


driver = webdriver.Firefox()

lista = [
    'https://rapidevolution.clickfunnels.com/jv-page-2',
    'http://Listhubpro.com/jv',
    'http://viralautopilotfunnels.com/jv',
    'http://giantvideokit.com/vol3jv',
    'http://www.thefivedalliance.com/jv',
    'http://CPAApex.com/jv/',
    'http://www.wpproassistant.com/partners/',
    'http://domainerelite.com/',
    'http://socialsurveys.io/jv/',
    'http://tubeviperx.com/jvinvite',
    'http://svensroadtoimsuccess.com/affiliates',
]

for url in lista:
    not_found = False
    name_required = True
    email_required = True
    button_required = True

    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(2)

try:
        name_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@*[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'name')]]")
        name_box.click()
        name_box.clear()
        name_box.send_keys('MyName')
    except:
        not_found = True

    try:
        email_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@*[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'email')]]")
        email_box.click()
        email_box.clear()
        email_box.send_keys('email@yahoo.com')
    except:
        not_found = True

    if not_found:
        print "here"
        for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@type='text']"):
            if name_required:
                try:
                    name_box = element.find_element_by_xpath(".[@*[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'name')]]")
                    name_box.click()
                    name_box.clear()
                    name_box.send_keys('MyName')
                    name_required = False
                    continue
                except:
                    pass

            if email_required:
                try:
                    email_box = element.find_element_by_xpath(".[@*[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'email')]]")
                    email_box.click()
                    email_box.clear()
                    email_box.send_keys('email@yahoo.com')
                    email_required = False
                    break
                except:
                    pass

            if (not name_required) and (not email_required) and (not button_required):
                break
# from here, the code is not doing what I want

    for element1 in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@type='submit'][preceding-sibling::email]"):
        if button_required:
            try:
                button = element1.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@type='submit'][preceding-sibling::email]").click()
                element1.click()
                element1.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
                #button_required = False
                continue
            except:
                try:
                    element1.find_element_by_xpath('/a').click()
                    #button_required = False
                except:
                    pass

    time.sleep(2)
    print button_required
```

I am kindly asking for your help as there are more than 10 days I am fighting with this situation.

Comment: I'd like to know this too. Didn't find something related to your question in documentation

Comment: Me neighter. Hopefully somebody will be able to help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
//*[@type="Submit"][preceding::*[@name="email" or @name="name"]]
```

Of course if you want it to match case-insensitively, then you’ll need to do the `translate(…)` thing for `"Submit"` and `"email"` and `"name"`:

```
//*[@type[translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = "submit"]][preceding::*[@name[translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') ="email" or translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') ="name"]]]
```

Comment: thanks. It works a little bit better. Could you please help me to integrate the translation to your line of code ? it's pretty complex.

Comment: Yeah, gimme a few minutes and I’ll post an updated answer.

Comment: @Alexander See the second XPath expression I added to my answer.

Comment: It's a great answer @sideshowbarker . Can you also think of anything else ? I'd like to have as many xpath's as possible to put them in a `try` / `except` block.

Comment: @Alexander I'd suggest writing up a different question, then :-) I don’t have any other suggestions I can think of on this one…

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one you can have a try

```
//*[@name='email' or @name='name']//following::*[@type='submit']
```

Comment: It's a great answer @J.Lyu . Can you also think of anything else ? I'd like to have as many xpath's as possible to put them in a `try` / `except` block.

Comment: @Alexander I can't work out any other way but if you replace **following** to **following-sibling** you are able to seach the elements which are in the same level in dom with previous node. So does preceding